# slick 2.0 I can not store the data as "<>" is not member of class operator

Tags: scala, slick

I defined the class strictly follow the User-Defined Features (http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.0-RC1/userdefined.html) and migration (http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.0-RC1/migration.html) :

```
case class MyID(value: Long) extends MappedTo[Long]
case class User(id: Option[MyID]=None,
            email: String,
            firstName: String,
            lastName: String,
            phone:String) 

class Users(tag: Tag) extends Table[User](tag, "users") {
def * = (id.?, email, firstName , lastName , phone )<> (User.tupled, User.unapply)
def id= column[MyID]("ID", O.AutoInc, O.PrimaryKey)
def email = column[String]("EMAIL", O.NotNull)

def firstName = column[String]("FIRST_NAME", O.NotNull)

def lastName = column[String]("LAST_NAME", O.NotNull)
def phone =column[String]("PHONE", O.NotNull)
}
```

but still meet compile error as:

```
[error] C:\assigment\slick-advanced\app\models\User.scala:28: value <> is not a
member of (scala.slick.lifted.Column[Option[models.MyID]], scala.slick.lifted.Co
lumn[String], scala.slick.lifted.Column[String], scala.slick.lifted.Column[Strin
g], scala.slick.lifted.Column[String])
[error]   def * = (id.?, email, firstName , lastName , phone )<> (User.tupled, U
ser.unapply)
[error]                                                       ^
```

why "<>" can not apply and is not member of User?

Comment: also posted here: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/scalaquery/Om5gHwuJiY4/aEiQmnLFpIgJ

Answer (score 0):

The types of your columns don't match the argument types of your case class. User `id.?` in you `*` projection.

Comment: Please add `.shaped` as suggested here https://groups.google.com/d/msg/scalaquery/Om5gHwuJiY4/aEiQmnLFpIgJ for a better error message